# Dispatching to the UI thread still required when using MVVM Light?

Tags: mvvm-light

I'm hoping this isn't too dumb a question: I just started using MVVM light (love it so far! ).  In the "before time" (ie before the use of MVVML), I had to ui dispatch any code that would hit a property setter that had an INotifyPropertyChanged event raised in it.

I had (incorrectly? ) thought that requirement would disappear when using MVVMlight.

I still have to use it, correct?  My experiments tell me a resounding yes.

So, heres the really stupid part - since there is a requirement to initialize the MVVML dispatcherhelper class somewhere, where I assume it saves the UI thread, why not have the RaisePropertyChanged call do the Dispatch automagically?  It seems like a common thing to do?

Not a criticism per se, more of a "how come it doesn't work this way" :-)

**Edit** *(copied from  from a comment by author)*

FWIW, I did this:

```
public class QViewModelBase : ViewModelBase { 
    protected override void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) { 
        DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI( () => base.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName)); 
    } 
    protected override void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(string propertyName, T oldValue, T newValue, bool broadcast) { 
        DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI( () => base.RaisePropertyChanged<T>(propertyName, oldValue, newValue, broadcast)); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: The question is good. However, I guess that Laurents rational lies in the design goal to support SL, WPF and WP7 in a single framework, plus allow the author of an application as much freedom as possible. Therefore, I think that Laurents approach is sensible! In addition, you always can modify your ViewModelBase in the way you did and ensure the behaviour in your project.

Comment: Oh yes, and I moved your code from the answer to [HiTech Magic](http://stackoverflow.com/users/201078/hitech-magic)'s answer to your OP to make your point clearer.

Comment: Just to be clear, I wasnt giving Laurent a hard time about not doing it (I am quite impressed with MVVMLight actually), it was more of a curiosity as to why you would ever *not* want to do this - even across WPF, SL & WP7.  They all have the same issue with UI thread affinity when notifying of a property change I think?
ps thank you for properly formatting my code- im new here, and had no idea how to get it to be readable :-)  gotta read the FAQ I guess

Comment: Never thought you did (giving Laurent a hard time that is). And yes reading the FAQ is a always good advice **;-)**. 

To make the code format properly just prefix 4 spaces, and add a new line at the start and bottom of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to my answer here: [Thread safe, Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755817/thread-safe-silverlight)

I highly recommend exactly what you are suggesting.

Comment: Yes, I am of the same opinion- the MVVMLight toolkit should automatically wrap UI thread affinity code inside RaisePropertyChanged using DispatcherHelper.  The reason for my original post was more like "Laurent is a smart guy, and it seems like it should work this way out of the box, so I must be missing why it doesnt".  Im kind of hoping Laurent sees this and tells me why the framework wouldnt want to do this by default.

Comment: FWIW, I did this:


    public class QViewModelBase : ViewModelBase
    {
        protected override void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI( () => base.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName));
        }
        protected override void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(string propertyName, T oldValue, T newValue, bool broadcast)
        {
            DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI( () => base.RaisePropertyChanged<T>(propertyName, oldValue, newValue, broadcast));
        }
    }

Comment: Re: *Please refer to my answer here: Thread safe, Silverlight* this is what `DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI` does.

Answer (score 1):

IMO you don't need to dispatch at all!
Only operations on ObservableCollection need dispatching.

Reference answer: [Accessing ViewModel properties from separate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524257/accessing-viewmodel-properties-from-separate-thread)